# Dynamically add views to Child of ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Hy all,

I'm triyng to add some dynamically generated views to a Linearlayout of a ChildView from an ExpandableListView. The code is:

```
 @Override
 public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_fragment_item_menu_child_view, null);

    TextView childName                              = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childName);
    TextView childDetails                           = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childDetails);
    LinearLayout childPriceWeightHolder_Single      = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childPriceWeightHolder_Single);
    LinearLayout childPriceWeightHolder_Multiple    = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childPriceWeightHolder_Multiple);

    JSONObject menuItem = null;
    try {
        menuItem = new JSONObject( getChild(groupPosition, childPosition) );
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(menuItem != null){
        childName.setText( menuItem.optString("name") );
        childDetails.setText( menuItem.optString("description") );

        final TextView tv1 = new TextView(context), tv2 = new TextView(context);

        if( menuItem.optJSONArray("advance_prices") == null || menuItem.optJSONArray("advance_prices").length() == 0 ){
            if(menuItem.optString("price") != null && menuItem.optString("price").compareToIgnoreCase("null") != 0){
                tv1.setText(menuItem.optString("price") + " " + menuItem.optString("currency_name"));
                tv1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            }

            if(menuItem.optString("weight") != null && menuItem.optString("weight").compareToIgnoreCase("null") != 0){
                tv2.setText(menuItem.optString("weight"));
                tv2.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));
                tv2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            }

            childPriceWeightHolder_Single.addView(tv1);
            childPriceWeightHolder_Single.addView(tv2);
        }else{
            // COMPOSED VIEW(multiple prices and multiple weights, etc...)
        }
    }

    return convertView;
 }
```

The problem is that after the first page, what the adapter generates new childs it keeps a reference or something to these dinamycally added textViews and it messes everything. I tried to add tv1.setId(..); but it didn't work.

Any solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Done it! Just add childPriceWeightHolder_Single.removeAllViews(); to the view you want to inflate(and inflated before), so it only adds the current dinamically genereated views!

Answer (score 0):

Basic example for expandablelistview is.. here....

Implement OnChildClickListener in your Activity and implemet this method..

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

   //Add new chid data in your list (ex ArrayLis or Array whatever you use)
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() // BaseExpandableListAdapter's adapter...


return true;
}
```

Is it work work for you?